# Where are the AirDrop files after transferring to Mac?

Tags: airdrop

I used AirDrop for the first time to move files from my iPhone to my MacBook. I read the brief information on the MacBook itself when set it up. The files transferred but I can't find them. They were photos and a brief video.

Any idea where the files might be?

Comment: In your downloads folder.

Comment: You should also get a notification on your Mac when the transfer completes. Clicking that notification will take you to the proper location.

Answer (score 5):

AirDrop defaults to the **Downloads** folder. When transferring from a device not associated with your iCloud account, i.e. someone else's iPhone or Mac, you may have the option to download to the **Photos** app for photos and videos. Check either of those and you should find the files.

As noted by Phong in the comments, clicking on the notification will take you to the file in Finder.